# Getting Error while running ReadyApi project through Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, soapui, ready-api

I am trying for continuous integration testing process by using Jenkins and Ready! API. So I have already installed Ready! API with valid license in Jenkins server. Created one POM file which is being used to execute my Ready! API project in Jenkins.

When I execute the project directly through Maven then its working fine but when I go for Jenkins then I am getting an error in Jenkins of:

```
No valid SoapUI NG license exists. Please enter absolute path of the license file (.zip or .key):
```

So here is the Maven POM file what I am using :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.zaloni.bedrock</groupId>
    <artifactId>Bedrock_integration-tests</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>4.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Integration Tests for Bedrock</name>
    <properties>
        <do.junit.report>true</do.junit.report>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!--Adding SoapUI Maven plugin-->
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                                <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                        <version>0.1.42</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <groupId>com.smartbear</groupId>
                <artifactId>ready-api-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <id>p1</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>${pom.basedir}/ProjectName/SoapUI-Test-with-Maven-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                            <!--testSuite>TestSuite 1</testSuite>
                            <testCase>TestCase 1</testCase>
                            <Make the jUnit results file-->
                            <junitReport>${do.junit.report}</junitReport>
                            <printReport>${do.junit.report}</printReport>
                            <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                            <!--reportFormat>PDF</reportFormat>
                            <reportType>TestCase Report</reportType>
                            <reportName>maven_pdf_report</reportName>
                            <outputFolder>C:\SoapUI\Support\soapui_maven_output</outputFolder>
                            <activeEnvironment>QA</activeEnvironment -->
                            <soapuiProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>soapui.home</name>
                                    <value>/home/ppanda/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.7.0/bin/</value>
                                </property>
                            </soapuiProperties>
                            <readyApiProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>soapui.home</name>
                                    <value>/home/ppanda/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.7.0/bin/</value>
                                </property>
                            </readyApiProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the Jenkins error:

```
[INFO] Building Integration Tests for Bedrock 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Bedrock_integration-tests ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Bedrock_integration-tests ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/jenkins/jenkins/jobs/Maven_SoapUI_Integration_Test/workspace/SoapUI_Test_with_maven/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Bedrock_integration-tests ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Bedrock_integration-tests ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/jenkins/jenkins/jobs/Maven_SoapUI_Integration_Test/workspace/SoapUI_Test_with_maven/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Bedrock_integration-tests ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Bedrock_integration-tests ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- ready-api-maven-plugin:1.7.0:test (p1) @ Bedrock_integration-tests ---
[WARNING] System property 'soapui.home' is not set! Using this directory instead: .Setting soapui.home value /home/ppanda/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.7.0/bin/
[WARNING] No base packages specified - no classpath scanning will be done
[INFO] Hibernate Validator 4.1.0.Final
[INFO] Adding module 'com.smartbear.ready.cmd.CommandLineModule
02:38:28,418 INFO [SoapUI] Adding [/home/ppanda/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.7.0/bin/ext/postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar] to extensions classpath
02:38:28,419 INFO [SoapUI] Adding [/home/ppanda/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.7.0/bin/ext/sqljdbc4.jar] to extensions classpath
02:38:28,419 INFO [SoapUI] Adding [/home/ppanda/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.7.0/bin/ext/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar] to extensions classpath
02:38:28,419 INFO [SoapUI] Adding [/home/ppanda/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.7.0/bin/ext/jsch-0.1.42.jar] to extensions classpath
02:38:28,419 INFO [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [/var/lib/jenkins/soapui-settings.xml]
02:38:28,834 WARN [SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory] Missing scripts folder [/home/jenkins/jenkins/jobs/Maven_SoapUI_Integration_Test/workspace/scripts]
02:38:28,835 INFO [DefaultSoapUICore] Adding listeners from [/home/ppanda/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.7.0/bin/listeners/demo-listeners.xml]
[INFO] Initializing database..
02:38:30,051 INFO [PluginManager] 0 plugins loaded in 2 ms
02:38:30,051 INFO [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded
[INFO] Waiting for changelog lock....
02:38:30,365 INFO [SoapUI] Adding [/home/ppanda/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.7.0/bin/ext/postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar] to extensions classpath
02:38:30,367 INFO [SoapUI] Adding [/home/ppanda/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.7.0/bin/ext/sqljdbc4.jar] to extensions classpath
02:38:30,367 INFO [SoapUI] Adding [/home/ppanda/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.7.0/bin/ext/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar] to extensions classpath
02:38:30,367 INFO [SoapUI] Adding [/home/ppanda/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.7.0/bin/ext/jsch-0.1.42.jar] to extensions classpath
02:38:30,367 INFO [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [/var/lib/jenkins/soapui-settings.xml]
02:38:30,371 INFO [DefaultSoapUICore] Adding listeners from [/home/ppanda/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.7.0/bin/listeners/demo-listeners.xml]
02:38:30,409 INFO [PluginManager] 0 plugins loaded in 0 ms
02:38:30,409 INFO [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded No valid SoapUI NG license exists. Please enter absolute path of the license file (.zip or .key):
[ERROR] java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.543 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-03T02:38:30-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 37M/480M
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.smartbear:ready-api-maven-plugin:1.7.0:test (p1) on project Bedrock_integration-tests: Ready! API Test(s) failed: Ready! API Test(s) failed:
[ERROR] No line found
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Any solution please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> You will need an activated license for the user account you are running the maven plugin with.  Did you activate a license for the user account that is running Ready API locally?  You can do online license activation with \bin\testrunner.

[Source](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Problem-in-integration-of-Ready-API-with-Maven/m-p/95074/highlight/true#M23221)

Futhermore see [Jenkins Plugin License Activation](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/about/licenses/activate/jenkins/start)

Comment: Hi, I want through http://readyapi.smartbear.com/about/licenses/activate/jenkins/license_not_found side but here I got some tips related to window machine so how can I do the same in linux machine .

Comment: Do we need to mention in the maven about our current license ?

Comment: As far as I understood the discussion, you have only to activate the license for the **right** user and that's it.

Comment: Hey, for SoapUI and Jenkins integration, do we require any license for Test server or something? We have SoapUI Pro license